# LiveAgent Chat: allow attachments only on case?

Tags: liveagent

During a live agent chat, the agent can request a file from the visitor.  When they click the "Request a file" button, they are prompted to first select which record to attach the file to, from the records that are currently onscreen in the chat.  For example:

[image: Chat file attachment dialog]

Is there any way to force all file attachments to be attached to the Case?  Either by eliminating the dialog, or removing all options except Case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked with our concerned Salesforce Product Development team on this scenario. It is currently not possible to customize this functionality.

Please consider logging this as an idea on [Salesforce IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/search#t=All&sort=relevancy)