# Allow limited type of objects while raising attachment request from agent?

Tags: liveagent, files

I have marked Agent **File Transfer Enabled** true for each Chat Agent Configuration:

[image]

Now agent can initiate file transfer.

When agent initiates file transfer it sees pop up like below:

[image]

When agent click on drop down menu he/she sees multiple object options:

[image]

Is there any way to limit number of objects available in the drop down or Salesforce shows as per objects accessible to the agent?
I want to allow only Cases and contacts.

Comment: See [this similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399320/liveagent-chat-allow-attachments-only-on-case) from the past. It is currently not possible to customize this functionality. Please consider logging this as an idea on Salesforce IdeaExchange

Comment: Posted idea: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000OXNnhUAH/allow-limited-type-of-objects-while-raising-attachment-request-from-agent